# Save image from uri to gallery on Xamarin Forms

Tags: image, xamarin, download, xamarin.forms

I need to download an image from an Uri and save it to gallery on Xamarin Forms.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use `HttpClient` to download the image from your given `Uri`. Most likely the `GetAsync` method will help. [See documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/cloud-services/consuming/rest/) for more info.

Once you have the file loaded in memory, you will have to store the image into storage. If you want to have the image publicly available (not just internally to your application), you will need to do this in a **platform specific manner**, because each platform has different approach to storing images into photos library.

You have to [look into **dependency service**](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/dependency-service/) concept for Xamarin.Forms, which allows you to create a shared, platform-agnostic interface and then provide platform specific implementations. You would then for example pass the in-memory image bytes to this interface and it would manage the platform-specific saving of the image.

For **Android** you will need to request internal storage access permission. See more details on in [Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/files.html).

For **UWP** you will need to declare the [`PicturesLibrary` capability](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) to be able to access user's pictures. You then access the location using `Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary` and then store the image there. See more info [in documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.knownfolders).

For **iOS** see [Xamarin recipe](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/media/video_and_photos/save_photo_to_album_with_metadata/) to see how to save images into user albums. You will utilize [`UIImage.SaveToPhotosAlbum` method](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/member/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImage.SaveToPhotosAlbum/p/MonoTouch.UIKit.UIImage+SaveStatus/). You will also need to request additional permission with `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription`. See permissions info [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/security-privacy-enhancements/#Accessing_Private_User_Data).